# Dapper dot net with mysql, either Fatal or insert all as NULL

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

my code

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO representative_dev.representative_users
                                (Username, Password, FullName, 
                                HomePhone, PhoneToCall, 
                                CompanyEmail, PersonalEmail, 
                                IsManager) 
                            VALUES (@Username, @Password, @FullName, 
                                    @HomePhone, @PhoneToCall,
                                    @CompanyEmail, @PersonalEmail, 
                                    @IsManager);";
            mycon.Open();
            int cnt = mycon.Execute(query,
                new
                {
                    txtUsername,
                    txtPassword,
                    txtFullName,
                    txtHomePhone,
                    txtPhoneToCall,
                    txtCompanyEmail,
                    txtPersonalEmail,
                    cbxIsManager
                });
            mycon.Close();
```

it gives me
"Fatal error encountered during command execution."

when i do another insert query in another case it works great, the different is that here i have cbxIsManager as a bool and in the db is a tinyint(1) and in the other case all is strings

if i add "Allow User Variables=true;" then i dont get the exception but in the db all values are null (checked that he gets values)

using ASP.NET at this project, console at the other, both FW4, mysql is 6.somthing (think 3)
the other code

```
        string query = @"INSERT INTO representative_dev.potencial_contact
                    (Name, Company_ID, Phone, Email, Department, Notes, SuperFriend, UpdateDate) 
                    VALUES (@Name, @Company_ID, @Phone, @Email, @Department, @Notes, @SuperFriend, @UpdateDate);";
        mycon.Open();
        int cnt = mycon.Execute(query,
            new
            {
                con.Name,
                con.Company_ID,
                con.Phone,
                con.Email,
                con.Department,
                con.Notes,
                con.SuperFriend,
                con.UpdateDate
            });
        mycon.Close();
```

any help would be appreciated

thx, ariel

EDIT:
when did this it worked

```
            string query = @"INSERT INTO representative_dev.representative_users
                                (Username, Password, FullName, 
                                HomePhone, PhoneToCall, 
                                CompanyEmail, PersonalEmail, 
                                IsManager) 
                            VALUES ('" + txtUsername + @"', '" + txtPassword + @"', '" + txtFullName + @"', 
                                    '" + txtHomePhone + @"', '" + txtPhoneToCall + @"',
                                    '" + txtCompanyEmail + @"', '" + txtPersonalEmail + @"', 
                                    " + cbxIsManager + ");";

            int cnt = mysql.ExecuteInsert(query);
```

still looking for help since i would like to use the dapper....

Comment: The problem is most probably because MySql uses a tinyint for its boolean representation while your model class (cbxIsManager) has the property as a boolean. You could try to cast your boolean to an integer before executing it with dapper.

Comment: I'm also using Dapper.NET with MySQL and no matter what I tried the parameterized inserts always lead to nulls getting inserted. I finally gave up and resorted to not using parameters and just explicitly using the values like in the EDIT above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class RepresentativeUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Pasword { get; set; }
    //etc
    public int IsManager { get; set; }
}

public void InsertRepresentativeUser(RepresentativeUser representativeUser)
{
    const string query = @"INSERT INTO representative_dev.representative_users
                        (Username, Password, 
                        IsManager) 
                    VALUES (@Username, @Password,
                            @IsManager);
                    select count(*) from representative_dev.representative_users";

    var count = DbConnection.Query<decimal>(query,
        new
        {
            representativeUser.UserName,
            representativeUser.Pasword,
            representativeUser.IsManager
        });
}
```

Main change is to use Query<> extension vs Execute. Execute does not return results and I saw you wanted some count to come back, e.g. "int cnt = mycon.Execute(query,".

I also wrapped the query into a method; now your client just needs to send a new RepresentativeUser to be inserted. This way you can also control the datatypes.

Hope this helps.
Good luck

Comment: no, it doesnt help, still get the same error, p.s. i am doing all this inside the RepresentativeUser object as .InsertToDb() since i have it as a webmethod that accepts RepresentativeUser, still its the same, the cmd throws the exception. thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `@`s with `:`s. It seemed to work for me:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO representative_dev.representative_users 
                 (Username, Password, FullName, HomePhone, PhoneToCall, CompanyEmail,
                  PersonalEmail, IsManager) VALUES (:Username, :Password, :FullName,
                  :HomePhone, :PhoneToCall, :CompanyEmail, :PersonalEmail, :IsManager);";
```